# Sort an object property list by Name C#

Tags: c#

I have an object which contains many properties of type string and whose name consists of a text and number like `Property1`, `Property3`, `Property12` ... etc.

I want to get a sorted list (OrderByDescending) of properties whose value is not null.

This means the property at the first position the should be the the property whose number (not the value) which is a part of name is highest.

**For Example:**
In the case that the list contains objects with following properties:

(Property Name: Value)

1. Property1: 3
2. Property2: null
3. Property3: 2
4. Property4: null

This should be the sorted list that I need:

1. Property3: 2
2. Property1: 3

Here is what I tried but it doesn't work:

```
var objectType= typeof(Type);
var result = objectType.GetProperties()
    .Where(p => p.Name.Contains("Property") && p.GetValue(object) != null);
    .OrderByDescending(p => p.Name);
```

Please can you help me to realize it?

Thanks!

Comment: you want to get the values of those properties sorted ?

Comment: The title doesnt match the post - where does sorting come in?  Seems like a bad design: aside from depending on names or name order, why isnt that an array or list of property values?

Comment: I firstly want to get the properties sorted. When it's done I would get the value of the property at the index zero (in the case of a descending sorting). Can you understand what I mean?

Comment: the type stored in those properties is decimal

Comment: Try creating a method `public int GetNumberFromName(string name) { ... }` that you can then use like this: `.OrderByDescending(p => GetNumberFromName(p.Name));`

Comment: Thank you for suggestion Peter. That helped me solve my problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved my problem:

creating a method public int GetNumberFromName(string name) { ... } that I can then use to sort my object list like this: .OrderByDescending(p => GetNumberFromName(p.Name));

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

You could try orderby after Where clause:

```
var objectType= typeof(Type);
var result = objectType.GetProperties()
    .Where(p => p.Name.Contains("Property") && p.GetValue(triangleView) != null)
    .OrderBy(c => c.Name);
```

Comment: I already tried it but it doesn't work with OrderBy(c => c.Name). It returns somehting like this: Property11, Property1, Property20, Property2 ...etc